# Big integer multiplication on R

Tags: r, permutation, biginteger

I am facing a problem of the following computation on R. I want to find factorial 10 multiplied with 0.1. I could have used factorial() function on R but in order to check the efficiency of packages "gmp" and "Rmpfr", I used factorialZ(). Surprisingly I found the multiplication turns out 0 (zero). It gives the output Big Integer ('bigz') : 0. How can I take care of this ? Any lead will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens (I thought it depended on whether the multiplicand had an exact binary representation, but I think I was wrong about that). More likely it's just an undefined behaviour - i.e. there's no specific reason that the package author should have made `bigz` objects play nicely with regular R `numeric` objects. If you want to divide by 10, just do that:

```
factorialZ(10)/10
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 362880
```

Or convert back to a regular R integer first:

```
as.integer(factorialZ(10))*0.1
[1] 362880
```

If you have a number that *can't* be represented as an R integer or numeric (e.g. > 1e310) but need to use it in operations with floating-point values, you can convert to `mpfr` type (high-precision floating point):

```
.bigz2mpfr(factorialZ(200))*0.1
1 'mpfr' number of precision  1248   bits 
[1] 78865786736479054733166935894034745829709731011205555800275415888196330271667643800669079467809137225619298895315986676109948164059578143835819967701344559489245054862932798359603276806168730010575811932061231243634893448846943919677538088311404392920603667803910252938083642743828224123449104546887425346845059274452636794880000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Ben Bolker,  thanks for your suggestion. Actually the above part is just an instance i wanted to see. My original calculations involve this multiplication by a random floating point generated from some other sources. So it is not possible to multiply manually. I want to know whether any dedicated procedure exists to take care of this kind of situation.

Comment: We need more context in order to provide a useful answer. Are the factorials you generate going to be so big that you need big integer types?  If you multiply by a value that's stored as standard (fixed-precision) floating point, then you're going to lose the precision of the big integer anyway. (Are the numbers so big that they can't even be stored in double precision floating point, e.g. > 1e310?)